# Anonymous user count using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security

I have managed to accomplish a couple features using Spring Security 3.0.5.  The first is that I want a count and list of users that have a specific role.  To accomplish this I instituted the `HttpSessionEventPublisher` and the spring configurations that go along with it.  With these settings I can easily get the list of logged in users no matter what their privilege level - unless they are anonymous (`ROLE_ANONYMOUS`).

I'm using the anonymous tag in my security XML:

```
<security:anonymous />
```

I can debug the anonymous users coming in though `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter` but the `SessionRegistry.registerNewSession` never gets called for these, most likely because there is no principal for anonymous users.

So I'm just looking for ideas.  I would love to be able to list the count for the sessions that are anonymous, along with other registered users.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` and override the `createAuthentication` method (it's meant for overriding).

Then since this method is called only on a new anonymous authentication, whenever it's called you can increment a counter somewhere, or count them in any way convenient for you. You just need to count the calls to the method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation of `counting anonymous's in Spring Security`.

```
public class ProxyAuthenticationFilter extends AnonymousAuthenticationFilter {

        private String key = "key";

        public ProxyAuthenticationFilter() {
            super(key);
        }

        public ProxyAuthenticationFilter(String key, Object principal, List<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
    super(key, principal, authorities);
        }

        @Override
        protected Authentication createAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {

            // do increment and store somewhere 

            return super.createAuthentication(request);
        }
}


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.anonymous().authenticationFilter(proxyAuthenticationFilter());
        }

        @Bean
        protected ProxyAuthenticationFilter proxyAuthenticationFilter() {
            return new ProxyAuthenticationFilter();
        }
    }
}
```